# Create new list within dictionary of lists if the same keys are there in a string

Tags: python

My code is as follows :
I have string that has header data and want create lists of dictionary with same keys values being created as a new list.

```
header ="Type : 0 Record Size : 0x10 id : 0x1 Version : 0x1 Bas : 0x1 Size : 0x10\
    Type : 0 Record Size : 0x20 id : 0x2 Version : 0x2 Bas : 0x2 Size : 0x20\
    Type : 0 Record Size: 0x30 id : 0x3 Version : 0x3 Bas : 0x3 Size : 0x30"

data_hb = {}
for line in header.split("\n"):
    if len(line) > 0 and len(line.split(":")) > 1:
        key, value = line.split(":")
        key = key.strip()
        value = value.strip()
        data_hb[key] = value
```

Output obtained :

```
{Type: 0,Record Size: 0x30,id: 0x3,Version: 0x3,Bas : 0x3,Size: 0x30}
```

Expected output:

```
{{Type: 0,Record Size: 0x10,id: 0x1,Version: 0x1,Bas: 0x1,Size: 0x10},
 {Type: 0,Record Size: 0x20,id: 0x2,Version: 0x2,Bas: 0x2,Size: 0x20},
 {Type: 0,Record Size: 0x30,id: 0x3,Version: 0x3,Bas: 0x3,Size: 0x30}}
```

Currently only last key value is obtained, its over-writing into only one list, while wanted 3 lists to be displayed.

Comment: You are repeatedly updating the same dictionary - you need to create a new dictionary at each iteration and append it to a list

Comment: Your input string has no line breaks, but your loop expects some. Can you fix?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are repeatedly updating the same dictionary - you need to create a new dictionary at each iteration and append it to a list

```py
data_hb_list = []
for line in header.split("\n"):
    data_hb = {}
    if len(line) > 0 and len(line.split(":")) > 1:
        key, value = line.split(":")
        key = key.strip()
        value = value.strip()
        data_hb[key] = value
        data_hb_list.append(data_hb)
```